# Is it possible to reuse a Chrome tab upon launch?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

As part of a script, I am launching Chrome with a URL:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.google.com
```

It works fine.

I would like, however, to reuse an existing tab with that URL if it is already open (so that there are no more than 1 tab open with that page after repeated starts of the script).

Is this something that can be done natively in Chrome?

Comment: Might help if you share the script where you're calling the URL

Comment: @spikey_richie: I added the effective command line that is started. The script is not that relevant, it could also be a start from the command line

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to see if you were passing in any arguments.